# C# Cannot Find IPAddress method MapToIPv4

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am using C# with Framework 4.5.1, and I want to use `MapToIPv4` but the compiler doesn't recognize it. It recognizes other methods in

[IPAddress API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress)

such as `Parse()` etc, but not `MapToIPv4 & MapToIPv6`. Looking around it could be the .NET version I am using but I checked through installed programs and i have the 4.5.1. Any ideas?

```
IPAddress ipv4dstAddr = ....;
IPAddress ipv6dstAddr = ipv4dstAddr.mapToIPv6();
```

I looked throuhg my registry after troubleshooting and it seems that I only have 4.0, despite seeing 4.5.1 in Installed Programs part of Control Panel

Comment: Parse is a static method - MapToIPv4 and MapToIPV6 are instance methods. Are you sure you're trying to call it correctly? Please show us a sample of the code.

Comment: I cant answer my questions yet but... it is because I am using Visual Studio 2010 and seems that I cannot use 4.5 Framework for that.

Comment: 4.5.1 is an in place replacement of 4. The registry is misleading.

Comment: @gravidThoughts: While that's true, it may be that VS is using the 4.0 reference assemblies. 4.5.x is a drop-in replacement for the "real" runtime assemblies, but not the reference assemblies, IIRC.

Comment: Basically, if you want to use .NET 4.5+, you need VS2012 I believe.

Comment: All right, that's what I thought